# Panels: Show sub terms and child nodes

Tags: 7, panels

I've just used panels to display child terms on taxonomy pages. For example If my heirarchy is like this...

```
Catalogue
--Category 1
----Sub Cat 1 (contains nodes)
----Sub Cat 2 (contains nodes)
----Sub Cat 3 (contains nodes)
--Category 2
--- Sub Cat 4 (contains nodes)
```

...the 'Category 1' page shows links to Sub cats 1, 2 and 3. That's working fine.

The problem is that once you get to one of the sub categories that contain nodes, the node teasers are not displaying. Is there a way of making these display?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

Build a [view](http://drupal.org/project/views), taking a term argument, and returning the tagged nodes. Output it in Panels. This will give you the greatest flexibility.

Or:

Look for a "Term to Node" relationship under "Context" in the relevant variant. There might a suitable relationship to pull in the nodes that way, but you may find it hard to control what the nodes look like.

Comment: There's a default `term_view` view which displays nodes. How would I output that using panels, assuming that's suitable? It does use the same URL as my new panel page (i.e. taxonomy/term/%term)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking? If you want to output the default term_view, just enable it?

Comment: If I enable it I can see the nodes but it overrides the panel page I created to show sub terms, as shown above. I'd like to be able to show sub terms where there are some and nodes where they exist. No terms hold both sub terms and nodes, just one or the other. Perhaps there's a way of targeting these lowest sub terms to show nodes and all others to show sub terms?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a single page with multiple variants (2 or 3 by the look of your structure) instead of multiple pages. Check out [Learn Page manager](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/21) if that didn't make sense to you.